# Embedded image in Email body appearing bigger in outlook but working fine in gmail

Tags: html, css

Hi I am facing a problem to display embedded image in email properly.
With the below code apart form outlook it works fine for any email server, gmail, aol. yahoo etc.

For outlook, it appears way bigger.
Can someone pls help?

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;width: 10%;font-family: arial, verdana;
padding: 10px;">
        <img  style="height: auto;width:100%;" src="https://xxxx.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015e0000000Cptss1&oid=00De00001005WWHi"  alt="XXXXX" title="XXXX" />

    </td>
```

Comment: who knows how outlook calculates a width of 100% .. did you try maybe a fixed pixel value?

Comment: @derHugo: No, I haven't. Actually I need to build a responsive email template. So wondering if fixed pixel would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img  style="width:600px;height:300px" src="https://xxxx.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015e0000000Cptss1&oid=00De00001005WWHi"  alt="XXXXX" title="XXXX" />
```

Remember in Outlook % width and height not working you need to give width and height in px. 
If you still face any problem please reply here again.
checkout which css property support in emailer you can follow this link .
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: this works but any way to make the image appear smaller for tablet/mobile devices? means i want to make it responsive.